# Regex Match for a small decimal number is Failing in Entity Framwork

Tags: regex, frameworks, entity

I am using below regular expression in one of the field in my model and saving the model to Database using Entity Framework.

```
[RegularExpression("^(0(\\.[0-9]+)?|1(\\.0)?)$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Message")]
public float Threshold{ get; set; }
```

It's working for almost all the numbers, except when I am trying to give the number "0.00001" it's showing error.

Can you suggest where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work for `1.0` and `0.1`? I think [it matches](https://regex101.com/r/EjcXsV/1) You also have to escape the dot to match it literally. Do you get the ErrorMessage or a different error? Are there rules related to string length?

Comment: yes it works for most of the cases except 0.00001. I am actually escaping the . which somehow i missed in  my question which i corrected it now .I am getting the Error messages. There is max string length rule but thats from the UI side .Also in the console when i try to look the vale of threshold its shows in scientiic notation like 1e-5  for other numbers it shown decimal .I am not sure this is related to issue or not .

Comment: Try to add another alternative for [exponents](https://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html) like for example [`^(0(\.[0-9]+)?|1(\.0)?|[0-9]+[eE]-[0-9]+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/id8WqK/1)

Comment: You do not need a regex to validate floats, you may write a custom validation method for that.

Comment: I don't know if that can help but maybe you can do :            `^[0-9]+(?:.[0-9]*)$`

Comment: Thnaks @Thefourthbird for the solution. Its working now for me

Answer (score 0):

To match your values, you could add another alternative `|[0-9]+[eE]-[0-9]+` for the existing alternation that matches the [exponent](https://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html) part:

`^(0(\.[0-9]+)?|1(\.0)?|[0-9]+[eE]-[0-9]+)$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/id8WqK/1)

Your regex matches:

- `^` Assert start of the string
- `(` Capturing group

  - `0` Match literally
  - `(\.[0-9]+)?` Optional capturing group that matches a dot and 1+ digits
  - `|` Or
  - `1(\.0)?` Match 1 and an optional capturing group that matches a dot and zero
  - `|` Or
  - `[0-9]+[eE]-[0-9]+` Match 1+ digits followed by `e` or `E`, `-` and 1+ digits
- `)` Close capturing group
- `$` Assert end of the string